# Where the statusFiles should be saved?

Tags: kotlin, ktor

As mentioned [here](http://ktor.io/features/status-pages.html), I tried to use `Status Files` with the below code:

```
install(StatusPages) {
    statusFile(HttpStatusCode.NotFound, HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized, filePattern = "#.html")
}
```

and saved the file as below:

[image]

But after running it, I got the standard 404 error, which means the file are not seen, do I need to add some thing, or I'm saving them in wrong place?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like `statusFiles()` does a `resolveResource(path)`, so it is looking at: `src/main/resources/` and in order to make it understand/see the `statusFiles` folder, which is lying inside the `resources` folder, the `filePattern` is required to be tuned little nit to reflect it, so the correct code is:

```
statusFile(HttpStatusCode.NotFound, HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized, filePattern = "statusFiles/#.html")
```